# PHP preg_replace - Don't match within h1 tags

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am using preg_replace to add a link to keywords if they are found within a long HTML string. I don't want to add a link if the keyword is found within h1 tags or strong tags.

The below regex nearly works and basically says (I think): If the keyword is not immediately wrapped by either a h1 tag or a strong tag then replace with the keyword that was matched, as a bolded link to google.

```
$result = preg_replace('%(?!<h1>)(?!<strong>)\b(bobs widgets)\b(?!<\/strong>)(?!<\/h1>)%i','<a href="http://www.google.com"><strong>$1</strong></a>', $result, -1);
```

(the reason I don't want to match if in strong tags is because I am recursing through a lot of keywords so don't want to link an already linked keyword on subsequent passes)

the above works fine and won't match:

```
<h1>bobs widgets</h1>
```

It will however match the keyword in the following text, because the h1 tag isn't immediately either side of the keyword:

```
<h1>Here are bobs widgets for sale</h1>
```

I need to make the spaces either side optional and have tried adding \s* but that doesn't get me anywhere. I'd be very grateful for a push in the right direction here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are the wrong tool for this job.  This has been discussed many times on Stack Overflow (such as the [most famous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) on the site).

What you need is an HTML parser, such as the [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).  Do yourself a favour and use something like this from the start.  Imagine what's going to happen when you run into an `<h1>` where someone has added an attribute, or perhaps someone has improperly closed the tags, so you have a mixed up order on a `</strong>` and a `</h1>`.  Getting things like that to work with a regular expression is not worth the trouble, and sometimes isn't even possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply zombat, I'll certainly look into the HTML parser you mentioned. I should have said that the HTML being processed isn't user-supplied and comes from another part of the script which takes plaintext and wraps it in <H1s> or <p> tags depending on their length. Is there a solution now do you think?

Comment: Should be okay as long as it's valid HTML, ie doesn't have '<' or various other characters that HTML has special feelings for in inappropriate places  (like the back of a volkswagen).  Once you learn to use the Simple HTML library (and this is not a large time investment) it's so much easier than dealing with regexes that there's no point in not using it, unless you're running this code on a pocket calculator.

Comment: so in other words you should escaping any of those characters by running the text through htmlspecialchars(): http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 1):

... just remember that eventually this approach will lead to sadness, and you'll need to start looking for a better approach. One way is to use 'tidy' to fix up your html into parseable xml, and then php offers a few xml manipulation APIs to work with the data.

Here's an answer anyway.

You can add some wildcards instead of the word boundaries. Something like this should do the trick:

```
([^<>]*)(bobs widgets)([^<>]*)
```

Then, add some more replacement markers to keep the remainder of your text in the output:

```
'$1<a href="http://www.google.com"><strong>$2</strong></a>$3'
```

Now hit save and hide behind the sofa ;)